# For-Loop ignoring break statement?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to stop the loop when I get a false result in my if statement but it's not working and I can't see what I'm missing. I added a label hoping that would be the solution but still nothing.

```
let a1 = [1321, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11];
let a2 = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19];

function comp(a,b){
  a.sort()
  b.sort()

  var result = true;

  if ( a === null || b === null) { return !result }
  if( a.length < 1 || b.length < 1 ) { return !result }

 loop_label: for (var i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i]*a[i], b[1],(a[i]*a[i]) == b[i])
    if(!(a[i]*a[i]) == b[i]) {
      return !result;
      break loop_label;
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Instead what happens is that it keeps looping through and returns true at the end but I want it to return false when one of the evaluations is false.

Comment: The `return` statement exits the function immediately.

Comment: In exactly what way is this "not working"?  While the `break` statement is superfluous because it will never be reached after a `return`, the loop *does* "stop" after a `return`.

Comment: Maybe it is because your console.log statement always puts out `b[1]` and not `b[i]` that you get the false assumption that it doesn't exit the code?

Comment: @Icepickle you're right that's a spelling error, good call.

Comment: Do you really want to mutate your input variables, by sorting them when they come to your compare method? The danger you might have here, is that these arrays could still be used somewhere else in your code, and after they go through your compare method, they will probably be mutated. I also think its good you check if your arrays are not null (but you sort before the check :'() and you probably don't have to go through all the items if the length of the arrays are different (now you stick to `a.length`, what if b.length is smaller than a.length). And are empty arrays the same (currently not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if must be like this:

```
if(a[i]*a[i] != b[i]) {
    return !result;
}
```

You don't even need `label` and `break` since return will already get out of the function for you and, hence, the loop will be evidently stopped.

Comment: You're right, I made this a lot more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

The `break loop_label;` is not reached, because the line above is: `return !result`. That ends the call to `comp` with a return value of `!result`.

Which is the opposite that would be returned in case the break would actually apply and `result` would be returned (not negated, the last line of the method).

So consider removing `return !result;` line in the loop, or change it to `return result;` to be the same as the final return -- whichever is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you structure like this, where `if` will skip over and `else` will do what you want

`if(!(a[i]*a[i]) == b[i]) {}
else{
    // do something here
}`